# Boosting popularity error as "Missing value for field [x]"

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get popularity boosting working as below. I use 2.0.2 version of ElasticSearch

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "should": [
                  {
                     "multi_match": {
                        "type": "best_fields",
                        "query": "search",
                        "fields": [                          
                           "Name^7",
                           "ShortDescription^6"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "OrderCount"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Although OrderCount is never null but rather 0, i am getting error message as

```
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "exception",
            "reason": "Missing value for field [OrderCount]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
      "reason": "all shards failed",
      "phase": "query",
      "grouped": true,
      "failed_shards": [
```

I checked with the query, if there is any null value but query returns no result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "missing": {
          "field": "OrderCount"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to set even "null_value": 0 as below but still getting this error message

```
},
"OrderCount": {
"null_value": 0,
"index": "no",
"store": true,
"type": "integer"
},
```

I extended my query even with the following filter below but error is sill there.

```
  "functions": [
            {
                "filter":{
                  "exists":{
                     "field":"OrderCount"
                  }
               },
               "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "OrderCount"             
               }
            }   
      }
```

What can it be the the problem? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out that setting `Index: no` is the problem. When I don't set it at all and not sure why I shouldn't set Index: no as I dont want this to be indexed. Doing as below works as charm but I dont understand the difference indeed. If anyone has explanation. I appreciate.

```
"OrderCount": {
"null_value": 0,
"store": true,
"type": "integer"
},
```